# How to use alb-ingress-controller in k8s cluster which installed by kops on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, kops

Want to use `alb-ingress-controller` on AWS.

Have installed k8s cluster by `kops`.

Followed this guide use `alb-ingress-controller`:

https://github.com/coreos/alb-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md

When check logs after run `$ kubectl apply -f echoserver-ingress.yaml`,

```
$ kubectl logs -n kube-system \
$(kubectl get po -n kube-system | \
egrep -o alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+) | \
egrep -o '\[ALB-INGRESS.*$' | \
grep 'echoserver\/echoserver'

[ALB-INGRESS] [echoserver/echoserver] [ERROR]: Error parsing annotations: Retrieval of subnets failed to resolve 2 qualified subnets. Subnets must contain the tag:kubernetes.io/cluster/cluster01.orange-test.dev.drecom.jp tag with a value of shared and the tag:kubernetes.io/role/alb-ingress tag signifying it should be used for ALBs Additionally, their must be at least 2 subnets with unique availability zones as required by ALBs. Either tag subnets to meet this requirement or use the subnets annotation on the ingress resource to explicitly call out what subnets to use for ALB creation. The subnets that did resolve were []. (cache hit)
```

I have set two subnets in every unique AZ for one special VPC. And set cluster name's value to `shared`, added a `kubernetes.io/role/alb-ingress`. Why can't pass it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add tags to your **subnets**?

In the walkthrough it says:

...

9. Add tags to subnets where ALBs should be deployed.

...